Create Task in planner for different request via form
How to create a flow where if those who select "business card" as a request and fill out that information on the Microsoft form will be made into a task in Microsoft planner. If those filling out the same form pick they want "custom apparel" as a request and fill out the information about that a task will be created in planner. They can only pick one request per form. They have 13 request options to choose from. My conditions do no work and my TRUE statements get skipped. How can I fix this?
What i have so far:
When a new response is submitted 
Get response detail
Condition1:OR Request details equal to BUSINESS CARDS
True:
A. Create a task (business cards)
Update task details
Condition2:OR Request details equal to Custom Apparel
True:
A. Create a task (apparel)
Update task details

first i did the simple branch option then I did the condition with the OR condition. Both flows failed

When you inspect the Flow run, what is the error message for the failure? Or did the TRUE branch of the step simply not fire? Power Automate is Case Sensitive. Why is BUSINESS CARDS in all caps, but Custom Apparel in Camel Case?
Here is an approach for troubleshooting:

write the value of the field Request detail into a Compose statement
in the condition, reference the output of the Compose statement
run the flow

Now you can inspect the flow run and see the actual value used in the condition. Take it from there.
